# Slicing pandas dataframe based on rearranged duplicates (or how to drop rearranged duplicates)

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, slice, object-slicing

I have a big dataframe with the format

```
   col1    col2    val1    val2
[0]A       B       0.8     0.1
[1]B       A       0.8     0.1
[2]A       C       0.3     0.9
[3]A       D       0.2     0.8
[4]D       A       0.2     0.8
```

As you can see, some rows are duplicated with only `col1` and `col2` reversed. For instance, row `1` is duplicate of row `0`, and row `4` is duplicate of row `3`.  Can you drop the duplicates based on the match of `col1`:`col2` being equal to those of `col2`:`col1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorting both columns by `np.sort` and assign back, then use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with specify some columns:

```
df[['col1','col2']] = np.sort(df[['col1','col2']], axis=1)
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['col1','col2'])
print (df1)
  col1 col2  val1  val2
0    A    B   0.8   0.1
2    A    C   0.3   0.9
3    A    D   0.2   0.8
```

Of remove duplicates by all columns:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates()
print (df2)
  col1 col2  val1  val2
0    A    B   0.8   0.1
2    A    C   0.3   0.9
3    A    D   0.2   0.8
```